# Custom sidebar for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, sidebar

Currently I have 2 custom post types -> Events and Food. Whenever I'm posting something I use taxonomies to act like categories for them.

The problem I have is: when I'm inside a taxonomy archive it shows my sidebar containing "Search" and "Categories" but I want "Search" to query only posts from that custom post type and "Categories" to show only those taxonomies from my custom post type (not categories).

Is it possible? Can someone give me an advice to start? I'm using a bought theme from TF.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom widget for search and term list and use some plugins that managed visiblity of it like [Display Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ah-display-widgets/) or try look for some complex search plugin, maybe [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) can do what you want